# id url routing with Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteorite, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I want to route to certain #id elements. I'm iterating through tempalate:

```
    {{#each posts}}
        {{> post}}
    {{/each}}
```

And in each post

```
<a href="#{{_id}}"><span class="anchor glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span></a>
```

For some reason its not working. The url changes, but I suspect this may have to do with template rendering. Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming you are using IR, you can search the [issues list](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues?state=open) for something like "hash anchor". I found a few helpful discussions, most notably [this one](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/248). Hopefully one of those suggestions works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming first you have a named route "post" set up in your Iron Router's routes, you can set it up via the named route with Iron Router's pathFor helper.  It will automatically recognize the id from the #each block:

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'post'}}"><span class="anchor glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span></a>
```

[See here for more details](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/dev/DOCS.md#path-functions-and-helpers).

Comment: no, im not going to a new page. I just want to scroll down to the right element in the page.